# Schematron bad pattern with sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, schematron

Hi I have XML like this:

```
<databaza>
<dvd>
    <movie>
        <number_of_character>2</number_of_character>
        <character>
            <character_id>1</character_id>
        </character>
        <character>
            <character_id>2</character_id>
        </character>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <number_of_character>4</number_of_character>
        <character>
            <character_id>1</character_id>
            </character>
        <character>
            <character_id>2</character_id>
            </character>
        <character>
            <character_id>3</character_id>
            </character>
        <character>
            <character_id>4</character_id>
            </character>
    </movie>
</dvd>
</databaza>
```

And schematron code:

```
    <pattern>
    <rule context="databaza/dvd/movie/character">
        <assert test="character_id &lt;= ../number_of_character">
         Element "character_id" is grater than element "number_of_character".</assert>
    </rule>
</pattern>

<pattern>
    <rule context="databaza/dvd/movie/character">
        <assert test="current()/character_id &lt; following-sibling::*[1]/character_id"> 
         Bad order. </assert>
    </rule>
</pattern>
```

And I have the problem with the parts where there are not another sibling. 
can you help me ?

I used these 2 patterns because I need  `<character_id>` in the order from 1 to max (the element `<number_of_character>`) so if you have better pattern which say that the numbers must be in these order please write it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you modify your last `assert` that way:

```
<assert test="(current()/character_id &lt; following-sibling::*[1]/character_id) 
               or not(following-sibling::*)"> 
            Bad order. </assert>
```

so that the rule is "neutral" for the last `<character>` sibling.